# Is possible to post a JSON file at a router location with the Iron framework?

Tags: json, rust, iron

I'm using the Iron web framework (for the Rust programming language) in an application and I have a path exposed to POST JSON data at using the [Router crate](https://github.com/iron/router).

It works but I have to percent encode my JSON data and append it as a string to the end of my HTTP POST request - which works but is a bit tedious and I'd like to eventually POST raw image files.

I'd like to be able to do something along the lines of the following curl command:

```
curl -v -i --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @some_local_json_file.json http://my_server_ip_address:3000/example_path/post/json_object_here
```

I'm currently getting a `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` error:

```
curl -v -i --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @some_local_json_file.json http://my_server_ip_address:3000/example_path/post/json
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying my_server_ip_address...
* Connected to my_server_ip_address (my_server_ip_address) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /example_path/post/json HTTP/1.1
> Host: my_server_ip_address:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 2354
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 22:44:03 GMT
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 22:44:03 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
Content-Length: 0

< 
* Connection #0 to host my_server_ip_address left intact
```

The meat of my `main` function looks like:

```
fn main() {
    // create the router
    let mut router = Router::new();

    router.post("/example_path/post/:json", post_to_documents);

    let mut mount = Mount::new();

    // mount the router
    mount.mount("/", router);

    Iron::new(mount).http("0.0.0.0:3000").unwrap();
}
```

And the `post_to_documents` listed above is along the lines of:

```
fn post_to_documents(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response>
{
    let document_url_encoded = req.extensions.get::<Router>()
                                             .unwrap()
                                             .find("json")
                                             .unwrap_or("/");
    // Just return Ok
    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Ok")))
}
```

I want to have the JSON data in the `document_url_encoded` variable. (I guess it's poorly named since it would not be url/percent encoded in this case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of how HTTP POST works, or at least how it works when exposed through Iron and friends. A POST request is sent in a separate part of the request from the URL / path information, and Iron exposes these two concepts separately.

You are using [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron/router) to map paths to functions and to extract simple parameters from the path. You need to *also* use [Iron Body Parser](https://github.com/iron/body-parser) to extract data from the POST body. It will automatically parse JSON for you, as well as give access to the raw binary data.

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate router;
extern crate mount;
extern crate bodyparser;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;
use router::Router;
use mount::Mount;

fn post_to_documents(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    match req.extensions.get::<Router>().and_then(|r| r.find("json")) {
        Some(name) => println!("The name was {:?}", name),
        None => println!("There was no name!"),
    }

    match req.get::<bodyparser::Json>() {
        Ok(Some(json_body)) => println!("Parsed body:\n{:?}", json_body),
        Ok(None) => println!("No body"),
        Err(err) => println!("Error: {:?}", err)
    }

    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Ok")))
}

fn main() {
    let mut router = Router::new();
    router.post("/documents/post/:json", post_to_documents, "new_document");

    let mut mount = Mount::new();
    mount.mount("/", router);

    Iron::new(mount).http("0.0.0.0:3000").unwrap();
}
```

I have a file called `input.json`:

```
{"key": "value"}
```

And I run this command:

```
curl -v -i --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @input.json http://127.0.0.1:3000/documents/post/awesome
```

With this output from the server:

```
The name was "awesome"
Parsed body:
Object({"key": String("value")})
```

I cannot explain why you are getting a 404 error.

This was done with

- bodyparser 0.7.0
- iron 0.5.1
- mount 0.3.0
- router 0.5.1

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks!